# Is Ubuntu 12.04 works fine on Lenovo G400 i3?

Tags: lenovo

I'm planning to buy new Laptop(lenovo g400), but i want to be sure i can run Ubuntu 12.04 on it. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! You might not be at the right address here, but you will probably find more here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It'll work. I think it will work really smoothly

Comment: Nope, but I looked about all the hardware.